# Counterexample: is there a solution of $\dot{x}(t)=-\nabla f(x)(t)$ with infinite length?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, gradient-descent

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded domain, $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ non negative and $x(t)$ a $C^1$ solution of
$$ \dot{x}(t) = -\nabla f(x(t)),\quad x(0) = x_0$$
Always exists $C>0$ such that
$$ \int \|\dot{x}(t)\|dt \leq C $$
uniformly in $x_0\in U$? If $U$ is not bounded, then it is easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: Are the limits of the time integration fixed? Also, just because $f$ is $C^1$ does not mean it is bounded if the domain is not compact; in the case where it is not bounded you can easily break things.

Comment: The integral is over all the domain of $x(t)$, i.e. it is the length of $x$. You are right about boundedness, I forgot to say that $f\geq0$

Comment: @Ian Anyway, how do you break things when $f$ is unbounded?

Comment: $f$ could be unbounded above too, consider something like $U$ being the open disk and $f(x)=1/(1-\| x \|)$. In this case $f$ is radial, so $\nabla f$ always points in the same direction. I think your question is more about whether $(x(t),f(x(t)))$ can spiral around but ultimately only move a finite vertical distance.